# Invaild_grant error when using outlook login with V2.0 endpoint API?

Tags: node.js, outlook, oauth-2.0, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have used 'simple-oauth2' npm module in my node.js project to enable outlook login in my MERN project.I have registered my application in [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/).We use the following api to get the access token of outlook login

```js
var credentials = {
  clientID: clientId,
  clientSecret: clientSecret,
  site: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common',
  authorizationPath: '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
  tokenPath: '/oauth2/v2.0/token'
}

var oauth2 = require('simple-oauth2')(credentials)
```

The above API works fine and logins the user if that user is a personal account. However, it throws a 'invalid_grant' error with error code of 7000 when we try to login using business account.Could anyone help me out this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm that your app registration is using `apps.dev.microsoft.com` (the v2 auth portal)?

Comment: @DmitryPimenov Yeah its is registered in the v2 auth portal

Comment: Can you share the scopes you're requesting?